# scrollbar of element overlaps block

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/nazarbroslaw/pen/PoYdJrR
how to overlap blue block completely? (restrictions: do not delete z-index of "content" class) ?

```
expected result https://prnt.sc/p75uk5
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted (or as an executable snippet, where applicable), and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: Search for similar questions regarding positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed a container within your absolutely positioned container, this then allows me to use the boundaries of this box with a child positioned absolutely.

If you remove and replace the commented out code in the css for the class 'pop'. You can have the content not touching the sides, just floating over the parent box.

Here is my attempt at understanding your requirements:

```css
.container {
 background-color: gray;
}

.content {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background-color: blue;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 z-index: 1;
}

.content-inner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.pop {
 width: 100%;
  /*width: 50%;*/
  height: 100%;
  /*height: 50%;*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
  /*top: 50%;*/
 left: 0;
  /*left: 50%;*/
 /*-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
 background-color: green;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="header">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inner">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          
     <div class="pop">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```